# I click over Item into recycler view, and It changes background color for two itemViews

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm newbie in android with kotlin. I have a recycler view with a Linearlayout. When  I click over itemView I change the background for select it. But the app changes background for two itemViews. I don't know what happen. This is my code:

MenuActivity

```
class MenuActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val section =  SectionParameters.builder().itemResourceId(R.layout.list_item_grid_menu)
        .headerResourceId(R.layout.header_layout)
        .build()

    private val categoryService= CategoriaServiceDbImpl()
    private val manageSharedPrefrences = ManageSharedPrefrences()
    private var namedbanko = ""
    private var defaultSection = 1
    private var indexDefaultSection = 0
    private var categories = emptyList<Categoria>()
    var categoryListAdapter: CategoryListGridRecycleAdapter? = null
    var summaryRecycleAdapter: SumaryRecyclerAdapter? = null

    var viewSection:View? = null
    var posIni:Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu)

        namedbanko = manageSharedPrefrences.getValueSharedPreference(SessionEnum.CONNECTION.KEY,SessionEnum.SESSION.KEY,this)
        /**
         * Secciones
         */
        sections(defaultSection,indexDefaultSection)
        /**
         * Lista de productos
         */
        val categoryDefault = this.categories.get(this.indexDefaultSection);
        val sectionAdapter = SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter()
        val productosService = ProductoServiceDbImpl()
        productosService.namedb = namedbanko

        val listProducts = productosService.getProductoByTipo(defaultSection)
        title_section_selected.text = categoryDefault.nombre
        sectionAdapter.addSection(ComponentStatelessMenu(this,"",listProducts,section ))
        val recycleView: RecyclerView = recyclerlist_menu

        val glm = GridLayoutManager(this,2)

        glm.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
                when (sectionAdapter.getSectionItemViewType(position)) {
                    SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_HEADER -> return 2
                    else -> return 1
                }
            }
        }

        //recycleView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager (this)
        recycleView.layoutManager = glm
        recycleView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true)
        recycleView.adapter = sectionAdapter

        val recyclerViewSummary : RecyclerView = recycler_summary
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerViewSummary.layoutManager =layoutManager
        this.summaryRecycleAdapter = SumaryRecyclerAdapter(this)
        recyclerViewSummary.adapter = this.summaryRecycleAdapter


    }

    fun sections(selectedSection:Number,position:Int){

        this.categoryListAdapter = CategoryListGridRecycleAdapter(this,selectedSection)

        val layoutSections = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        layoutSections.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL
        recycler_sections_menu.layoutManager = layoutSections
        recycler_sections_menu.overScrollMode = View.OVER_SCROLL_IF_CONTENT_SCROLLS

        if(this.categories.isEmpty()){
            this.categories = getSections()
        }else{
            var i = 0
            while(i<this.categories.size){
                this.categories.get(i).selected = StateEnum.N.VALUE
                i++
            }
        }

        categoryListAdapter?.setCategoryList(this.categories)
        recycler_sections_menu.adapter = categoryListAdapter

        if(position > 0){
            recycler_sections_menu.scrollToPosition(position.toInt()-1)
        }

        /*val namedb = connectionService.getNameDb(this.applicationContext)
        categoryService.namedb = namedb
        val listCategory = categoryService.listProductByCategory(0)

        val section_category =  SectionParameters.builder().itemResourceId(R.layout.list_item_section)
            .headerResourceId(R.layout.header_layout)
            .build()
        val sectionAdapterCategory : SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter = SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter()
        sectionAdapterCategory.addSection(CategoriasStatelessSection(getString(R.string.title_sections),listCategory,section_category))

        val recycleView: RecyclerView = recycler_sections_menu
        val lm = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        lm.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL

        recycleView.layoutManager = lm
        recycleView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true)
        recycleView.adapter = sectionAdapterCategory*/

    }

    fun refreshProductsSection(category: Categoria){

        val sectionAdapter : SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter = SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter()

        val productosService = ProductoServiceDbImpl()
        productosService.namedb = namedbanko

        val listProducts = productosService.getProductoByTipo(category.codigo)

        sectionAdapter.addSection(ComponentStatelessMenu(this,"",listProducts,section ))
        val recycleView: RecyclerView = recyclerlist_menu

        val glm = GridLayoutManager(this,2)

        glm.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
                when (sectionAdapter.getSectionItemViewType(position)) {
                    SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_HEADER -> return 2
                    else -> return 1
                }
            }
        }

        //recycleView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager (this)
        recycleView.layoutManager = glm
        recycleView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true)
        recycleView.adapter = sectionAdapter
    }

    fun changeColorSelectedSection(view: View,position: Int){

        if(this.viewSection!=null){
            this.viewSection!!.setBackgroundResource(0)
        }
        view.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorSectionSelected))
        categoryListAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

        this.viewSection = view
    }

    fun getSections():List<Categoria>{
        categoryService.namedb = namedbanko
        return categoryService.listCategorias()
    }
}
```

The MenuActivity class saves the last itemView selected, then It refreshes it.
This activity has the function changeColorSelectedSection that notifies the change. This is my Adapter for Recycle:

```
class CategoryListGridRecycleAdapter(val menuActivity: MenuActivity,val categorySelected:Number):RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    private var listSections = listOf<Categoria>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return CategoryListViewHolder(menuActivity, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_section,parent,false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val categoryViewHolder = holder as CategoryListViewHolder
        /*if(this.categorySelected == listSections[position].codigo)
        {
            listSections[position].selected = StateEnum.S.VALUE
        }else{
            listSections[position].selected = StateEnum.N.VALUE
        }*/
        categoryViewHolder.onBindItemView(listSections[position],position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = listSections.size

    fun setCategoryList(listOfCategory:List<Categoria>){
        this.listSections = listOfCategory
    }

}
```

The bind for item is into CategoryListViewHolder:

```
class CategoryListViewHolder(val menuActivity: MenuActivity, itemCategoryView:View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemCategoryView) {

    /**
     * Función que le coloca las características a la sección dibujada
     * @param itemSection Objeto con la infornación de la categoria
     * @param position Posición de la categoria que se está configurando
     */
    fun onBindItemView(itemSection: Categoria, position: Int){
        itemView.title_section_menu.text = itemSection.nombre

        /**
         * Cargar imagen BLOB
         */
        val blob:ByteArray? = itemSection.imagen

        try {
            itemView.imgSection.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE
            itemView.imgSection.adjustViewBounds = true
            if(blob!=null) {
                val inputStream = blob!!.inputStream()
                itemView.imgSection.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream))
            }else{
                itemView.imgSection.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_star)

            }
        }catch (e:Exception){
            print("Error onBindItemView "+e.message)
        }

        /**
         * Click para cargar los prodictos de la sección
         */
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
                view -> actionSection(view,itemSection,position)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Función que cambia el fondo de selección
     * @param itemSection Objeto de la sección seleccionada
     * @param view Vista del front que se seleccionó
     * @param position Índice del objeto seleccionado
     */
    private fun actionSection(view: View,itemSection: Categoria,position: Int){
        menuActivity.changeColorSelectedSection(view,position)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a `RecyclerView`, which recycles its views. So when you are changing the background of a specific view and that view is used again when you scroll down in the list, the background will be the same as it is currently set for that item. For example, if I see 5 items on my screen, and I click on item 1 making it selected, the view for item 1 is now selected. But when I scroll down to item 6 and item 1 goes off screen, the view for item 1 is reused for item 6, and is still in its state.

In order to counter this, you should not be keeping track of the selected view but rather the selected item, and then update the view according to which item it represents. In a `RecyclerView`, one view is not for one item, it is used for multiple items.

Here's a solution with minimal code changes:

MenuActivity

```
var selectedPosition: Int = -1

...

fun changeColorSelectedSection(position: Int) {
    selectedPosition = position
    categoryListAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

CategoryListViewHolder

```
...

fun onBindItemView(itemSection: Categoria, position: Int) {
    ...

    val backgroundResourceId = if (position == menuActivity.selectedPosition) R.color.colorSectionSelected else 0
    itemView.setBackgroundResource(backgroundResourceId)
}
```